# Aggregation function (AVG) running total per week / year BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, average

I need an average duration per week per id

`SELECT ID, EXTRACT (WEEK FROM starttime) as week1, AVG(duration) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d',starttime) ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  as avgperweek FROM DB WHERE DATE(StartTime) between "2020-01-01" And "2020-10-10"`

expecting to see like that

[image]

but it is ungrouping by exact day time

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT ID, 
  EXTRACT (WEEK FROM starttime) as week1, 
  AVG(duration) as avgperweek 
FROM DB 
WHERE DATE(StartTime) between "2020-01-01" And "2020-10-10" 
GROUP BY ID, week1
```

Comment: When changing WEEK to MONTH or DAY, the numbers are approximately the same and not correct

Comment: which means that your average pretty steady - right? if you still not convinced  - provide example/sample of input data and desired result so we can check what you think is wrong